# Ruby - Trying to select a tab which has hover dropdowns

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm new to all of this so apologies if I'm not clear.

I am creating an automated test scenario for an admin section of a website.

I am trying to navigate to a tab labelled content, which also happens to be a hover drop down option.

The code looks like this:

```
    <body class="dmundra" style="visibility: visible;">
<div class="imageBG"></div>
<div class="bannerBG"></div>
<div id="doc3" class="yui-t7">
<div id="hd">
<div id="menu">
<ul id="root" class="level1 horizontal">
<li class="level1 Active">
<a href="http://stag.web.est.wjec.co.uk/c/portal/layout?p_l_id=34885ddb-3537-4a79-a02c-0550c5087d5c&p_p_id=EXT_21&p_p_action=0&&dm_rlout=1&r=1399625953307">
<div class="tabLeft">
<div class="navMenu-title">Home</div>
<div class="navMenu-subtitle">Tasks & Dashboard</div>
<div class="navMenu-arrow"> </div>
</div>
</a>
<span class="tabRight"></span>
<ul class="level2 dropdown" style="position: absolute; top: 90px; left: 10px; visibility: hidden;">
<li class="level2 dotCMS_EXT_21">
<a href="http://stag.web.est.wjec.co.uk/c/portal/layout?p_l_id=34885ddb-3537-4a79-a02c-0550c5087d5c&p_p_id=EXT_21&p_p_action=0&&dm_rlout=1&r=1399625953308">
<span></span>
Workflow Tasks
</a>
</li>
<li class="level2 dotCMS_EXT_DASHBOARD">
<a href="http://stag.web.est.wjec.co.uk/c/portal/layout?p_l_id=34885ddb-3537-4a79-a02c-0550c5087d5c&p_p_id=EXT_DASHBOARD&p_p_action=0&&dm_rlout=1&r=1399625953308">
<span></span>
Dashboard
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="level1 ">
<a href="http://stag.web.est.wjec.co.uk/c/portal/layout?p_l_id=931f0b26-92c1-420b-8fbf-e48089040921&p_p_id=EXT_BROWSER&p_p_action=0&&dm_rlout=1&r=1399625953308">
<div class="tabLeft">
<div class="navMenu-title">Site Editor</div>
<div class="navMenu-subtitle">Web & File Browser</div>
<div class="navMenu-arrow"> </div>
</div>
</a>
</li>
<li class="level1 ">
<a href="http://stag.web.est.wjec.co.uk/c/portal/layout?p_l_id=71b8a1ca-37b6-4b6e-a43b-c7482f28db6c&p_p_id=EXT_11&p_p_action=0&&dm_rlout=1&r=1399625953308">
<div class="tabLeft">
<div class="navMenu-title">Content</div>
<div class="navMenu-subtitle">Manage your Site</div>
<div class="navMenu-arrow"> </div>
</div>
</a>
<span class="tabRight"></span>
<ul class="level2 dropdown" style="position: absolute; top: 90px; left: 266px; visibility: hidden;">
<li class="level2 dotCMS_EXT_11">
<a href="http://stag.web.est.wjec.co.uk/c/portal/layout?p_l_id=71b8a1ca-37b6-4b6e-a43b-c7482f28db6c&p_p_id=EXT_11&p_p_action=0&&dm_rlout=1&r=1399625953308">
<span></span>
Content Search
</a>
</li>
<li class="level2 dotCMS_EXT_BROKEN_LINKS">
<a href="http://stag.web.est.wjec.co.uk/c/portal/layout?p_l_id=71b8a1ca-37b6-4b6e-a43b-c7482f28db6c&p_p_id=EXT_BROKEN_LINKS&p_p_action=0&&dm_rlout=1&r=1399625953308">
<span></span>
Link Checker
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have tried accessing it by name, link and class but to no avail.

This was my last attempt having read a thread that I thought was similar.

```
When(/^i select content tab$/) do
    while @browser.div(:id, 'navMenu-title').a(:text, "Content").exists? do
    @browser.div(:id, 'navMenu-title').a(:text, "Content").click 
end
```

Comment: Do you know what library (eg jQueryUI) you are using to generate this tab control? I am guessing we need the associated javascript and style sheet to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It was using a Dojo toolkit. However we managed to find a solution thanks to P.S. But thank you very much for responding

Answer (score 0):

`navMenu-title` is class not id as you write it in you code.

Try to do it like this,

```
When(/^i select content tab$/) do
  while @browser.div(:class, 'navMenu-title').link(:text,"Content").exists? do
  @browser.div(:class, 'navMenu-title').link(:text,"Content").click 
end
```

I did not test it,but I think it will work.

Try to use,it will work

```
liObject=@browser.li(:class => "level1", :index => 2)
liObject.div(:class, 'navMenu-title').click;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That was probably from where i'd been changing thin gs to try to get it to work. For some reason it just doesnt click the link. I passes in the scenario but it definitely doesnt go to the page. I just cant work out why.

Comment: I did not get what you want to say.Please tell clearly?

Comment: Sorry. When running my scenario with the edited code you provided the step passed however it shouldn't have as the tab that is meant to be pressed in the step isn't. The next step in my scenario is just a check for a title on the new page and that fails because its not on the correct page. Does that make more sense?

Comment: can you provide the complete html so that I can try it on my machine.?

Comment: I have change my code try to use `link` in place of `a` in this code.Then tell me weather it is working or not?

Comment: Thanks but having the same issue as before. I have added a bit more of the html code above which might help. It seems that the step only looks at while @browser.div(:class, 'navMenu-title').link(:text,"Content").exists? which is why it is passing, and moves on before doing the action of the click

Comment: Try to use liObject=@browser.li(:class => "level1", :index => 2)
liObject.div(:class, 'navMenu-title').click; In Place of that code

Comment: Thats great, i amended it to liObject=@browser.li(:class => "level1", :index => 2).click and it works! Thank you very much. Really appreciate the help